# Using jQuery to produce a tooltip error message for ASP.net textbox on blur

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

First, I know there are many methods for doing this, so please don't hesitate to post your solution if it does not fit exactly what I am trying to say in the title.

I would like to produce an elegant looking error message for ASP.net textboxes, on **blur** (leaving the scope of an element in jQuery), if they did not pass validation.  One great example of this is, of course, on Stack Overflow itself, when filling out some of the various textboxes here.  If you tab over them without filling them out or do not meet the specifications of the textBox, then a nice looking error message pops up next to them, generally to the upper right of the textbox and visually disappears as soon as you meet the specifications required.

In this example, we are looking at an ASP.net textbox called OtherBox.  I have my validation functions already made and they work correctly, so I have a template for where I want to place my code, but I don't know the best/most modular way to do so:

```
$("#<%=OtherBox.ClientID %>").blur(function () {
    if (ValidationFunction(OtherBox)) {
        var OtherBoxError = document.getElementById('<%=OtherBoxError.ClientID %>');
        $(OtherBoxError).show();
        $(OtherBoxText).animate({ backgroundColor: "#FF9494" }, 200);
        //Additional code to make tooltip appear
    }
    else {
        var OtherBoxError = document.getElementById('<%=OtherBoxError.ClientID %>');
        $(OtherBoxError).hide();
        $(OtherBoxText).animate({ backgroundColor: "white" }, 200);
        //Additional code to make tooltip disappear
    }
});
```

I did take a look at [jQuery UI's tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/), which *looks* quite similar to what I want but looks like it only appears onMouseOver, whereas I would want mine to appear onBlur (and only when validation doesn't pass).  Perhaps I am not fully understanding the API.  I also found some solutions online which simply create a CSS div next to the textboxes, hide it in jQuery, and then make it appear, which is not very modular but i suppose is simple to implement and customize (as i said before, if your solution features this but you really like it, this is fine!).  I would prefer to use Javascript/jQuery/VB.net/ASP.net for my solution, as I am working on making things more *dynamic* and using these languages allows me to reuse the code throughout my site.

Summary: I want to create a visually appealing, dynamic/modular for all ASP.net textboxes, and polite error message, onBlur (as user moves on from focus on that element) in jQuery/.net code.

---

Sources, Updates, and Edits:

Comment: http://osvaldas.info/examples/elegant-css-and-jquery-tooltip-responsive-mobile-friendly/

Comment: The example Saj posted uses mouseenter/mouseleave to determine when to display the message, whereas I would like to use onBlur.  However, it is a very good tutorial.